# Can someone highlight the key difference between CRLF Injection, HTTP Response Splitting and HTTP Header Injection?

Tags: appsec, owasp

I believe each one of these is closely interlinked, for instance, HTTP Response Splitting will occur in event of CRLF characters injection (%0d%0a) and this will also involve injection of HTTP headers which control the HTTP responses such as Set-Cookie & Location response headers.

Answer (score 1):

[CRLF Injection](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/93.html) (CWE-93) is the general vulnerability that applies to multiples line-based protocols (HTTP, SMTP, Log file).

[HTTP Response Splitting](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246931/HTTP%20Response%20Splitting) is the ability to **start earlier the body section** of the HTTP response. HTML injection will be possible.

[HTTP Header Injection](https://www.gracefulsecurity.com/http-header-injection/) does not target the body but only the **headers section** of the response.